# Help deriving the general linear wave equation $d^2y/dx^2=(1/v^2)d^2y/dt^2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, differentiation

How do I derive the General Linear Wave Equation $$d^2y/dx^2=(1/v^2)d^2y/dt^2?$$

My teacher differentiated the general wave function $f(x + vt)+g(x - vt)$ twice with respect to both variables to get $d^2y/dx^2$ and $v^2d^2y/dt^2$, and then somehow combined them to get $$d^2y/dx^2=(1/v^2)d^2y/dt^2,$$ but I don't remember how he did it.

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiating twice just as you said. Then to combine them, you can do a few different things:

- Visually compare the two expressions, and note that they're identical except for a multiplicative constant, or
- divide the two expressions and see if you actually do get $v^2$ or $1/v^2$, or
- multiply your expression for $\partial^2 y/\partial t^2$ by $1/v^2$, and check if it's actually equal to your expression for $\partial^2 y/\partial x^2$

They all amount to the same thing; seeing if your expression for the second derivatives satisfy that differential (wave) equation.